# How to tell SBT to display Javadoc @author tag?

Tags: sbt, javadoc, author

I'm currently tidying a Javadoc for a PlayFramework project.

I know I need to use `sbt doc` to generate the Javadoc, it's working fine.

I also know that in order to display the `@author` tag with the `javadoc` command, you need to use `javadoc -author`.

But I don't have access to the `javadoc` command, only to `sbt doc`.

I already tried `sbt doc -author` but it's not working.

Is there a way to display the `@author` tag using the `sbt doc` command?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you can do `javacOptions in doc ++= Seq("-author", "Zenoo")`.

Comment: @marcospereira I don't want to specify the author directly, I want it to display the `@author` tag that is written in the comments of each function.

Comment: `@author` tag cannot be applied to methods. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#wheretags

Comment: @marcospereira Aw, that's a bummer. And if I want to display the `@author` tag from the class comments ?